# Writing a systemd timer for Prey

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to write a systemd timer to run [Prey](http://preyproject.com). I wrote:

**prey.service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Open source anti-theft solution for laptops, phones & tablets.

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/share/prey-tracker/prey.sh
```

**prey.timer:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Open source anti-theft solution for laptops, phones & tablets.

[Timer]
OnStartupSec=5min
OnUnitActiveSec=1h

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

It seems to work, but I'm in doubt about the [Install] section. There's a network.target. Does it mean that If I replace basic.target with network.target the timer will start running when the systems has network connection? If that is the case, can I remove the OnStartupSec=5min line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network.target is just a generic unit other services can depend on. It depends on the services, which are required by the network.target. If the network.target requires NetworkManager, it only ensures NetworkManager is started before any network dependent service is started.

Comment: So it doesn't ensure that the system has network connection?